Volume change of a deformable cylinder with a uniform spinning angular velocity
Consider a deformable cylinder without gravity with a uniform spinning angular velocity and the cylinder is not in contact with anything. In theory this cylinder shouldn't change its cross sectional area or volume as it spins with a uniform angular velocity. But in finite element simulation is it possible for the volume or cross section area to change in time as it spins around its own central axis?

For a solid cylinder undergoing rotation about its axis, the formulation is as follows:
As reckoned by an observer rotating with the cylinder (non-inertial frame of reference), the only displacement is in the radial direction u(r).  The principal strains in the radial and hoop directions are, respectively $$\epsilon_r=\frac{du}{dr}$$and $$\epsilon_{\theta}=\frac{u}{r}$$From Hooke's Law (3D), the principal stresses in the radial and hoop directions are $$\sigma_r=E\frac{(1-\nu)\epsilon_r+\nu\epsilon_{\theta}}{(1-2\nu)(1+\nu)}$$and$$\sigma_{\theta}=E\frac{(1-\nu)\epsilon_{\theta}+\nu\epsilon_{r}}{(1-2\nu)(1+\nu)}$$where E is Young's modulus and $\nu$ is the Poisson ratio.
The radial stress equilibrium equation for this system is $$\frac{d\sigma_r}{dr}+\frac{\sigma _r-\sigma_{\theta}}{r}+\rho \omega^2r=0$$The above sense of equations, when combined, lead to a 2nd order ODE in the radial displacement u(r).
Boundary conditions are that u = 0 at r = 0 and $\sigma_r=0$ at r = R.

Your stress-strain relationships are assuming plane strain. If it is free to expand in the $z$-direction then the plane stress relationships are more appropriate. For volume change you should then include the $z$-component of strain as well, $\Delta V/V_0 = \epsilon_r+\epsilon_\theta+\epsilon_z$.

The assumption is that the axial strain is zero.

Sorry, just edited my comment as you responded. If the cylinder is free to expand in the $z$-direction, then the plane stress stress-strain relationships are more appropriate.

But I guess this gets messy depending on the length to radius ratio of the cylinder. Plane-strain may be the only way to go to avoid end effects. Otherwise it is a full 3D problem.

I agree totally.  Assuming plane stress would be the same as treating it as a disc.

@looksquirrel101  I wonder why there could be any end effects?  Aren't the strains z independent regardless of whether it's plane strain or plane stress?

There can be end effects if the cylinder length is on the same order as the cylinder diameter, depending on the loading on the ends.

right when there's transverse forces. Let's assume there's no external force. Then under plane stress and plane strain strains should both be z independent

I’m mot sure I understand what you’re asking.

@feynman - There are Poisson's ratio effects. The radial and hoop stresses cause strains in the $z$-direction. In general, these strains will be incompatible with a stress-state that has $\sigma_{zz}=0$. The plane strain assumption is good if the cylinder is long compared to its radius and you are looking at the state far, i.e. several times the radius, from the ends. If the cylinder is very thin, then the plane stress assumption is better. In between, you need a full 3D analysis.

I agree totally with this

@looksquirrel101 I totally agree. By z independent, I don't mean there's no z strain or stress, I mean strain fields aren't functions of z but could be those of r.

@feynman - You can have generalized plain strain where $\epsilon_{zz} = constant$ and then $\sigma_{zz}$ is a function of $r$ and $\theta$. But this would be the solution for a cylinder with specific end conditions, and those end conditions would not be traction-free.


In theory this cylinder shouldn't change its cross sectional area or
volume as it spins with a uniform angular velocity.

That's not correct.
The material of the cylinder is in tension along its radius due to the centripetal force required for circular motion and the effect of the inertia of the material (that effect referred to as the centrifugal force in the rotating frame of the cylinder). That tension may increases its radius compared to that of a non rotating cylinder. The effect is similar to that of the bulging of the Earth at its equator.
The amount of increase will depend on its angular velocity and the modulus of elasticity (stiffness) of the material. Generally for most solids the increase would be slight.
I'm sorry but I am not familiar with finite element simulation. But I would not expect the radius to change in time as electrostatic intermolecular forces of attraction will ultimately limit the deformation.
Hope this helps.

OP is specifically asking if the mesh of a FEM simulation will deform under the rotation. Your answer is unrelated to this.

@KyleKanos I am responding to his incorrect statement "In theory this cylinder shouldn't change its cross sectional area or volume as it spins with a uniform angular velocity" and not FEM. I think Chet Miller is doing the same. If it was you who down voted our answers I respectfully request you reconsider it.

I gave you that upvote.

@ChetMiller. Thank you and ditto.

@BobD   Thank you very much for the answer. I wonder if any elasticity texts discuss a spinning circle with a uniform initial angular velocity released at t=0 (no external force thereafter) and the solution afterwards?

@feynman did you mean “tests” not “texts”?

@BobD textbooks

Materials are deformable volumetrically, so that, even if the cylinder is infinitely long (so that the axial strain is zero), it can still deform radially, and its cross sectional area and volume can increase under rotational loading.  The deformation can be calculated precisely using Hooke's law in 3D, Newton's 2nd law, and the strain-displacement equations.

OP is specifically asking if the mesh of a FEM simulation will deform under the rotation. Your answer is unrelated to this.

@KyleKanos. In my judgment, your interpretation of what the OP is asking is totally incorrect. He is saying that, according to his understanding, for this system, the volume and cross sectional area of the cylinder should not change, but his finite element analysis shows a change in both of these.  He is trying to discern why. My answer addresses this, and indicates that a change in volume and area should indeed be expected.

ad hominems aside, there is a singular question in the post: in finite element simulation is it possible for the volume or cross section area to change in time as it spins around its own central axis? Hence, OP is specifically asking about FEM. Your answer doesn't address that in any way.

@KyleKanos I stand by what I said.

I wonder if any elasticity texts discuss a spinning circle with a uniform initial angular velocity released at t=0 (no external force thereafter) and the solution afterwards?

Are you talking about a spinning hoop?  I don't need a textbook for this.

@ChetMiller maybe a spinning hoop is also helpful but right no need of a textbook for that. A circle is more complicated, which I'm asking
